# How do you shift a sigmoidal curve to the right?

Tags: functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

How do you shift the function $1$ $/ ( 1 + e ^ {-x} )$ to the right without altering the shape of the curve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try - e.g. if you use a software - plotting $x$ vs. $1/(1+e^{-(x-a)})$, where $a$ is the amount of the shift. This is the same as plotting $x+a$ vs. $1/(1+e^{-x})$.

Answer (score 5):

To shift any function $f(x)$, simply replace all occurrences of $x$ with $(x-\delta)$, where $\delta$ is the amount by which you want to shift the function. This is also written as $f(x-\delta$).